# Canvas context's stroke() makes transparent border, instead of fully opaque?

Tags: html5-canvas

I had a quick question regarding the ctx function `stroke` along with the usage of `rect`. In my code, I draw a `rect` and fill it with **red**. I want to also add a **green** border around the `rect`, but when I use `stroke` it seems to create a transparent border, rather than a fully solid line. Why does it do this by default?

Img of result:

[image]

My code:

```
        var ctx = Canvas.ctx;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);

        /*
         *  CONTAINER
         */
        ctx.fillStyle = this.primaryColor;
        ctx.fill();

        /*
         *  CONTAINER BAR
         */
        if(this.borderColor){
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.borderColor;
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        /*
         *  INNER BAR
         */
        var per = this.percent;

        if(per > 0){
            //the width of the actual loading bar that appears
            //inside the entire box
            var innerWidth = Math.floor(this.width*(per/100));

            ctx.fillStyle = this.secondaryColor;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x+1, this.y+1, innerWidth-2, this.height-2);
        }

        /*
         *  TEXT
         */
        if(this.text){
            ctx.textAlign = this.textAlign;
            ctx.font = this.font;
            ctx.fillStyle = this.textColor;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.textX, this.textY);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas draws its lines straddling your pixel coordinate. So a lineWidth=1 vertical line at x=20 will be drawn from 19.5 to 20.5.

To help clarify your rectangle follow these 2 hints:

- Assign the rect's x,y,width,height as integers
- Set translate(0.50,0.50) before drawing the rect(s) and unset translate(-0.50,-0.50) afterwards

You can read more about the "why?" here:

http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html

Note that these hints help with vertical & horizontal lines, but don't help angled lines & curves.